# Swift: how to use tags to access UITextField properties

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to use tags on 4 UITextFields to not only find with field was selected (I know this), but to then also change the text or properties of the selected text field (I don't know this). How can this be done directly?

I'm aware that I could create an array of the text fields and compare the tag to that, but that seems like an unnecessary step if I could instead do something like:

```
textfield(at tag).text = "Something"
```

If I can only use an array, then I'll have to write out a 4-case statement, so it seems like a more inefficient way to assign a field.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
guard let texF = self.view.viewWithTag(yourTag) as? UITextField else { return }
texF.text = "Something"
```